# My coin isn't showing on GUI

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monero-wallet-cli, daemon

[image]

I just transferred my XMR to my monero GUI wallet from Binance but it hasn't registered on my wallet. Can someone help me out here? Can someone look at the image and let me know what I need to do to rectify this issue? Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem. I sent some XMR from MyMonero wallet to my Gui Wallet and never arrived. Do I have to sync. with daemon before? Daemon is taking a very long time. Address is correct. And showing the transaction was completed in the MyMonero desktop wallet.

Comment: @CoinGuest & Ultimate Keeper -  Can you please try the guide I linked?